# Why aren't hyphens or dashes allowed in hashtags?

Tags: tagging

Why is underscore allowed in hashtags(e.g #hello_world) but not dash(e.g #hello-world)?

And why don't Twitter and other applications allow digit-only hashtags e.g #123? [Edit: got the answer to this in response]

Comment: Ampersands seem to be outlawed too...

Answer (score 9):

The octothorpe/hash (#) symbol has been considered the symbol for "number" way before it was used for tagging in social media. "#1" has always been "number one". If Twitter allowed numeric-only hashtags, people would write things like "#123" to mean "number 123" but Twitter would mistakenly consider it as a hashtag.

Comment: Perhaps this is the same reason for no dashes? #123-456-1232, both numbers and dashes are commonly used in phone numbers

Comment: How the fact that dashes are used in phone numbers is related to hyphen usage in hashtags? #foo-bar-baz is no phone number.